# How to kill a QtQuick QML Application if the UI Thread is blocked?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

How can I kill my QtQuick QML Application if the UI thread is blocked for more than an x Millisecond Timeout?

I've found an example (https://github.com/KDAB/KDToolBox/tree/master/qt/ui_watchdog) that states it

> monitors the main thread and breaks the program whenever its event loop hasn't run for `MAX_TIME_BLOCKED`

but I don't understand what they mean by "hasn't run". Do they mean no event has been processed of the event loop for the given time?
Also is the main thread of a QtQuick QML Application the UI Thread?

I'd appreciate a short explanation

Comment: "Hasn't run" means that the event loop didn't process events for time MAX_TIME_BLOCKED, because some method is executing longer than that and blocks the event loop. "Main thread" means the thread where the QGuiApllication and QQuickview etc live in,c so the main/main UI thread. Not to be confused with the QtQuick render thread.

Comment: Thanks @FrankOsterfeld for the explanation. If you would repost it as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.